# Why the data is not displayed in the view file in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a blade file, with the below code.

```
<div id="id1">0</div>

<div id="id2">0</div>

 <div id="id3">0</div>
```

The `0` in each div should be replaced by `time()` from the controller.

**Controller**

```
 public function get($divId = null)
    {

     return UpdatedTime::dispatch($this->getTime($divId));
    }
     public function getTime($divId )
    {

     // pusher
        $options = array(
            'cluster' => 'ap3',
            'useTLS' => true
        );

        $pusher = new Pusher(
            env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            $options
        );

        $pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'UpdatedTime', ['target' => $divId, 'value' => time()]);


    }
```

I could get the events triggered in **pusher**, but not in the view file.

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
    var data = '';
    ajax = $.ajax({
      url: '/getTime/' + node.id,
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
         //parse the server side response
         console.log(data);
         ajax = null;
      }
    });

    //node.innerHTML = ajax.data;

  });
});
// Pusher
    var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
        cluster: 'ap3',
        encrypted: true
      });
   // Subscribe to the channel we specified in our Laravel Event
      var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
   // Binding a function to a Event
     channel.bind('App\Events\UpdatedTime', function(data){
     document.getElementById(data.UpdatedTime.target).innerHTML = data.UpdatedTime.value; //**It is not working**
```

**Event file**

```
  public function __construct($timechanged)
    {
       $this->timechanged = $timechanged;

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('my-channel');
    }
```

**Routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/getTime/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TimeController@getTime');
```

Why I couldn't get the data in the view file, After visiting the URL `http://www.project.test/getTime/2` gives the blank page. I need the div with the time() for the particular ID.

How could I do this?
Could anyone please help?
Thanks

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById("id" + data.UpdatedTime.target)...`

Comment: @Cuong Le Ngoc  after passing  document.getElementById("id" + data.UpdatedTime.target) , It is not working.

Comment: Sry. You mean your pusher part not working or ajax part?

Comment: Pusher part is working, I could get the ID and the time() for that particular ID in Pusher. The problem is , If I type http://www.project.test/getTime/2 // I could not get the time() for the Id:2 in my view . It displays a blank page. How could I get this done?

Comment: Take a look at Laravel's log to see what's wrong. Shouldn't that url be `project.test/getTime/id2`? `id2` is the `id` attribute of the div

Comment: Yes, I need the Id attribute of the div, There are 3 div's with 3 different Id's. If I pass the Id in the URL, `the time() `for the particular Id should be displayed on the view page in the browser. Yes, It should be `project.test/getTime/id2`

Comment: Could you please help me how to check laravel logs, since I am new to laravel @brombeer

Comment: Laravel's log is in your project `/storage/log/` folder. Anything new added to the log gets appended to the end/bottom of the file

Comment: Thank you, got [2021-05-14 06:02:21] local.ERROR: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed at Queue.php:157)  this error at the bottom of the file